# Crop images set with google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

with python and python image library (PIL), I can crop a set of images in a directory.

If I have a set of images in google drive,

how I can crop this with a script?

Comment: In your situation, is this method useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no straightfoward image processing capabilities available in Apps Script. You'll have either expose your Python as a web service and call it from Apps Script or use the Drive REST API to access the files from your Python app.