# Image crop with AppScripts in Sheets or Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am evaluating Google Sheets with AppScripts for a report generator. The requirements include inserting images from Google Drive. One of the input image has a fix format, which I need to crop. ( So the dimensions of the original image and the dimensions of the crop is known.)

I am looking for a solution to achieve this outcome, but I am struggling. I looked into the following methods:

- No image crop function in the Drive API
- No image crop ( only resize) for the Sheets [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) object
- No image crop for the `=IMAGE()` function
- Manually you can create a drawing, add an image and crop it:

  - But you can't do this from AppScripts
  - You can't access the image within the drawing as an OverGridImage object. ( Which would allow you to replace it's image.)
- You can use the Slides API `replace(imageUrl, crop)`

  - Is it possible to embed/link the slide into the sheet via AppScript?

Is there any other workaround? ( Even if it means creating a new file in drive?)

EDIT: Obviously there is the solution to call an external API, or to use GCP services such as CloudFunctions ( which are not free). However I am hoping for an AppScript solution. ( Or using a compatible JS library.)

Comment: No, there is no tool for that within Apps Script and Drive/Sheets API. But I guess there are third party APIs out there that can crop images. If that's the case, you could call them with `UrlFetch` and add the cropped image to the sheet.

Comment: https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/08/06/cropping-images-in-google-slides-using-google-apps-script/

Comment: @Cooper Great article, actually made me think about a dirty workaround. What if I use a Slide to crop the image and then use `getBlob()`. Would that return the full image or the cropped part only?

Comment: Cross referencing how crop can be done in slides: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251248/would-it-be-possible-to-crop-image-using-google-app-script-without-using-any-thi

Comment: I tried in sheets to crop an image and use `getBlob()` or `getAs('image/png')` but both returns the full image, not the cropped area so this is a dead end.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the crop of image using Google Apps Script.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly cropping image using Google Apps Script. This has already been mentioned by [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741147/image-crop-with-appscripts-in-sheets-or-drive#comment112734751_63741147). So in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround for cropping image using Google Apps Script.

In this workaround, I use Microsoft Powerpoint and Google Slides. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Create Microsoft Powerpoint (PPTX data) by setting the page size.

   - In this case, the width and height of the image left by the crop are set. This is used as a window of image.
   - When the converted PPTX data is unzipped, the data can be analyzed as the XML data. Fortunately, at Microsoft Docs, the detail specification is published as Open XML. So in this case, Microsoft Docs like XLSX, DOCX and PPTX can be analyzed using XmlService of Google Apps Script. In this workaround, the PPTX data is directly created by including the page size. I think that this method will be also useful for other situations.
   - When the method of "presentations.create" of Slides API can be correctly used, this is not required. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/create)
2. Convert PPTX data to Google Slides.
3. Insert the image, that you want to do the crop, to the created Google Slides.

   - At that time, the crop of "top" and "left" is subtracted from the origin of coordinates. Because the origin of coordinates of Google Slides is the upper-left corner.
4. The thumbnail image is retrieved using [the method of "presentations.pages.getThumbnail" in Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail).

By above flow, the cropped image can be retrieved as a blob.

In this sample script, an image is cropped using the parameters using Google Apps Script. In this case, the script reflecting above flow is a bit complicated. So here, I would like to introduce the sample script using a Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#editimage) Of course, you can see the whole script there.

### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please install ImgApp of the Google Apps Script library. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#how-to-install) And in this case, [please enable Drive API and Slides API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const id = "###"; // If you want to crop the image on Google Drive, please set the file ID of the image here.

  const object = {blob: DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob(), crop: {t: 50, b: 100, l: 200, r: 100}};
  const blob = ImgApp.editImage(object);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

- This sample script crops an image on Google Drive and the cropped image is created to the root folder.

  - `crop: {t: 50, b: 100, l: 200, r: 100}` means that the crop size of `t`, `b`, `l` and `r` are the top, bottom, left and right, respectively. The unit is pixel.
- About the maximum image size, you can see it at [Limitations for Inserting Images to Google Docs](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/9414d22de2ff30216269ca7be4bce462). In this sample script, `25,000,000 pixels^2` is the maximum size of the image.

### References:

- [Understanding the Open XML file formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats)
- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [editImage() in ImgApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#editimage)

Comment: I like your thinking!
My workaround was to host my own PHP script which gets the image and the crop parameters and return the cropped image. It is not scaling well and may involve additional costs for hosting the PHP server. ( In case it is already paid.) Also it is likely slower than your solution.

Comment: @Adam Ocsvari Thank you for replying. This is one workaround using Google Apps Script. I think that there are several workarounds. So please think of this as one of them. If my workaround was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: Is there a way to crop an image blob, using gas script, where the crop is done not by coordenates but by detecting the white space around and removing it? I used your sugestion to export a range in sheets to PDF then export as PNG using an API service, but the resulting PNG has this huge white. background behind the SPARKLINE graph. Is this https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp capable of removing whitespace? Thanks @Tanaike